# How to code tridiagonal matrix with periodic elements

Tags: matrix

friends! I've never worked with matrices in Mathematica before so I'm asking for some help.

I have to find determinant of such matrix 100x100.. How can I do that?
[image]

Thanks a lot for advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 10;
sa1 = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> a, Band[{2, 1}, {n, n}] -> {b, c}, 
    Band[{1, 2}, {n, n}] -> {b, c}}, {n, n}];
MatrixForm[sa1]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Det@sa1
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FullSimplify@Det@sa1
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sa2 = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> a, Band[{2, 1}, {n, n}] -> {b, b, c, c}, 
    Band[{1, 2}, {n, n}] -> {b, b, c, c}}, {n, n}];
MatrixForm[sa2]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Det@sa2
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FullSimplify@Det@sa2
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]